# Resize crash libvpx

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw, webm, libvpx

I built libvpx(using cygwin, win7 x32, mingw). I did this steps:

1. Run "cygwin.bat" from mingw console;
2. Run "mintty";
3. ./configure --prefix=d:/qt4.8/mingw --target=x86-win32-gcc;
4. make

All built normal, but if I run test_libvpx.exe to test It crashes while testing resize:

```
...
[----------] 3 test from VP8/ResizeTest
[ RUN      ] VP8/ResizeTest.TestExternalResizeWorks/0
```

and there win crashes.
Regardless of whether or not applying some patches, it crashes any way.(in CHANGELOG there is this line : " Bug fixes: ... -Fix potential encoder dead-lock after picture resize")

This is my config.log:

```
# ./configure --prefix=d:/qt4.8/mingw --target=x86-win32-gcc
Configuring selected codecs
  enabling vp8_encoder
  enabling vp8_decoder
  enabling vp9_encoder
  enabling vp9_decoder
Configuring for target 'x86-win32-gcc'
  enabling x86
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #ifndef __ILP32__
    2   #error "not x32"
    3   #endif
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
-o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
./build/make/configure.sh: line 285: -E: command not found
  enabling runtime_cpu_detect
  enabling mmx
  enabling sse
  enabling sse2
  enabling sse3
  enabling ssse3
check_cflags -msse4
check_cc -msse4
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -msse4 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
  enabling sse4_1
check_cflags -mavx
check_cc -mavx
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -mavx -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
  enabling avx
check_cflags -mavx2
check_cc -mavx2
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -mavx2 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-mavx2"
  using yasm
check_cxxflags -O3
check_cxx -Werror -O3
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -Werror -O3 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -O3
check_cc -O3
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
  enabling use_x86inc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1       unsigned int e = 'O'<<24 | '2'<<16 | 'B'<<8 | 'E';
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1       static inline function() {}
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1       static __attribute__((always_inline)) function() {}
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_header pthread.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #include "pthread.h"
    2   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wall
check_cxx -Werror -Wall
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Werror -Wall -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wall
check_cc -Wall
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wdeclaration-after-statement
check_cxx -Werror -Wdeclaration-after-statement
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Werror -Wdeclaration-after-statement -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
cc1plus.exe: warnings being treated as errors
cc1plus.exe: error: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
check_cflags -Wdeclaration-after-statement
check_cc -Wdeclaration-after-statement
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wdisabled-optimization
check_cxx -Werror -Wdisabled-optimization
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Werror -Wdisabled-optimization -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wdisabled-optimization
check_cc -Wdisabled-optimization
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wpointer-arith
check_cxx -Werror -Wpointer-arith
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Werror -Wpointer-arith -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wpointer-arith
check_cc -Wpointer-arith
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wtype-limits
check_cxx -Werror -Wtype-limits
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Werror -Wtype-limits -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wtype-limits
check_cc -Wtype-limits
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wcast-qual
check_cxx -Werror -Wcast-qual
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Werror -Wcast-qual -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wcast-qual
check_cc -Wcast-qual
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wvla
check_cxx -Werror -Wvla
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Werror -Wvla -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wvla
check_cc -Wvla
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wimplicit-function-declaration
check_cxx -Werror -Wimplicit-function-declaration
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Werror -Wimplicit-function-declaration -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
cc1plus.exe: warnings being treated as errors
cc1plus.exe: error: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
check_cflags -Wimplicit-function-declaration
check_cc -Wimplicit-function-declaration
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wuninitialized
check_cxx -Werror -Wuninitialized
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Werror -Wuninitialized -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wuninitialized
check_cc -Wuninitialized
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wunused-variable
check_cxx -Werror -Wunused-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wuninitialized -Werror -Wunused-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wunused-variable
check_cc -Wunused-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_cxxflags -Wunused-but-set-variable
check_cxx -Werror -Wunused-but-set-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Werror -Wunused-but-set-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wunused-but-set-variable"
check_cflags -Wunused-but-set-variable
check_cc -Wunused-but-set-variable
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wunused-but-set-variable -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wunused-but-set-variable"
check_cxxflags -Wno-unused-function
check_cxx -Werror -Wno-unused-function
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Werror -Wno-unused-function -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
check_cflags -Wno-unused-function
check_cc -Wno-unused-function
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
  enabling postproc
check_cxx
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
    1   int z;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
g++ -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.cc
  enabling unit_tests
check_header stdio.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #include "stdio.h"
    2   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_ld
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   int main(void) {return 0;}
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -c -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -m32 -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.x /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o
check_header stdint.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #include "stdint.h"
    2   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_header pthread.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #include "pthread.h"
    2   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_header sys/mman.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #include "sys/mman.h"
    2   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
C:/Users/BOBUR/AppData/Local/Temp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c:1:22: error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
check_header unistd.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #include "unistd.h"
    2   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
check_header vpx/vpx_integer.h -I/c/downloads/libvpx-git
check_cpp -I/c/downloads/libvpx-git
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
    1   #include "vpx/vpx_integer.h"
    2   int x;
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
gcc -fno-common -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual -Wvla -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wuninitialized -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-function -I/c/downloads/libvpx-git -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1288-26667.c
```

How to solve it? Did I build it correctly?

Comment: Finally I built it follow [this](http://build.webmproject.org/jenkins/view/libvpx%20nightly%20tests/job/libvpx%20unit%20tests%20(multi-target)/lastSuccessfulBuild/arch=x86-win32-gcc/consoleFull)